# Maintain a Link to Subviews in View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Here's my situation: I have a `UIViewController` that manages a hierarchy of subviews, perhaps as shown below:

[image: View hierarchy]

This view is built from a `.xib`.  I would like to be able to maintain access to each subview of topView – that is, I want a pointer to each so that I can, for example, say something like:

```
[button1 setText:@"Hello!"];
```

Usually, to do this, I wire up each element to which I would like access using Interface Builder, resulting in a header that looks something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    __weak IBOutlet UIView *view;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
}

@end
```

These instance variables are `__weak`, which is fine, since by the time my view controller "gets" them, they're already owned by my view controller's root view (which, confusingly, I labeled "topView" in my quick diagram).  In fact, I want these references to be weak – when my root view is released, so too should all its subviews be released.  Great.

But let's say I want to create a new element of the UI, maybe a custom button, entirely in code.  I'll call this element `CustomViewClass`, which will be subclassed from `UIView`.  The instance of `CustomViewClass` that I will create will be called `customButton`.  As with the other subviews of my view, I would like "access" to `customButton` so that I can interact with it.  I know, however, that like any other subview, `customButton` will be owned by its superview, and that's how it should be – again, I want it to be released whenever my view is released.  This makes me think that I should declare this view as a `__weak` instance variable or property of my view controller.  Let's do that:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    __weak IBOutlet UIView *view;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
    __weak CustomViewClass *customButton;
}

@end
```

Then, in my implementation:

```
@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    customButton = [[CustomViewClass alloc] init];
    [[self view] addSubview:customButton];
}
@end
```

As you've probably already realized, this won't work, and the compiler will throw a warning to boot.  Something like:

```
Assigning retained object to weak variable; object 
will be released after assignment
```

I currently dodge this sort of warning with some very poor style:

```
@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CustomViewClass *customButtonLocal = [[CustomViewClass alloc] init];
    [[self view] addSubview:customButtonLocal];
    customButton = customButtonLocal;
}
@end
```

That way, I get what I want:

1. An instance of CustomViewClass on the screen...
2. ...with exactly one owner, its superview...
3. ...and no lingering variables (customButtonLocal is released immediately after the block ends).

But this can't be the "right" way to do this.  So, finally, my question:

**How *should* I be allocating and instantiating this programmatically-created `__weak` variable without using this middle-man workaround?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `CustomViewClass *customButton` a strong reference.

The reason why you usually declare variables for your subviews as `__weak IBOutlet` is that the existence of these links does not imply ownership. Subviews are owned by the object instantiated from a NIB/Storyboard. You own that object directly, and you also own its dependent objects indirectly.

The `customButton` is a different story: you create it programmatically, so your NIB/Storyboard does not own it. Therefore, you should make the reference to it `__strong` (which is the default when there are no ARC modifiers).

Comment: @JonasAlves Mind being more specific than that? What specifically causes memory leak? Under what circumstances? It is 100% clear that the answer did not cause a memory leak to the OP, so I would really appreciate your explanation.